# Is it possible to filter a pymongo cursor?

Tags: python, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am querying a MongoDB collection using pymongo in Django. First, I make a general filtering like
`cur = db.variants.find({"tags" : { "$in" : keywords}})`
and based on checkbox value from the frontend form, I want to filter the cursor again. I am looking for something like this.

```
if exn: #my checkbox 1
        cur = cur.filter(func = exn)
```

```
if non_synon: #my checkbox 2
        cur = cur.filter(conseq = non_synon)
```

This can be done using mongoengine. I want to know whether I can do this in Pymongo. Can someone please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't filter a cursor directly, but you can adjust the query to `find()` to bring in additional filters, e.g.

```
query = {"tags" : { "$in" : keywords}, "field1": "filter1", "field2": "filter2"}
cur = db.variants.find(query)
```

Comment: It works..!!! Thanks